# How to log nuxt server side network requests?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Is there some way how to log all network requests which are done by nuxtjs on server side?

I'm already using `node --inspect` to enable chrome console, but network tab is missing there.

Thanks a lot for any tip.

Comment: *How to log nuxt server side network requests? :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm using axios nuxt plugin (https://axios.nuxtjs.org).

I've created a plugin to extend it (https://axios.nuxtjs.org/extend.html):

```js
export default ({$axios, store}) => {
  $axios.onResponse(response => {
    console.log(`[${response.status}] ${response.request.path}`);
  });

  $axios.onError(err => {
    console.log(`[${err.response && err.response.status}] ${err.response && err.response.request.path}`);
    console.log(err.response && err.response.data);
  })
}
```

- `onError()` logs errored requests
- `onResponse()` logs successfull requests

Here is a sample output:

```
[200] /dashboard/rights/user
[200] /dashboard/rights/segment
[200] /dashboard/user/me
[400] /group/entries?group_id=undefined
{ status: 'error',
  codeStatus: 400,
  detail:
   [ { message:
        '"group_id" with value "undefined" fails to match the valid object id pattern',
       path: 'group_id',
       type: 'string.regex.name' } ] }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I didnt have much luck with either approach in the other answers. What eventually worked for me was adding a `ssr: false` to `nuxt.config.js` to make it a SPA instead of an SSR and debugging on the browser console.‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Nicolas' solution.

Once you created the axios plugin in your Nuxt app, you could add it to your Nuxt config file and set the `mode` to `server` as you want to run it on *server-side*.

More on Nuxt plugin [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/).

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/axios', mode: 'server' },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to log the requests **served by *your* nuxtjs app** in server side rendering mode.

Therefore, Axios is not the answer because it is used to *make* requests, not serve them.

The challenging part is figuring out how to get into the server rendering part. I have the same requirement and have decided to **make the nuxtjs middleware and use [Express](https://expressjs.com) as my server**. Then I configure logging in Express. This works well for me because I can add other routes, e.g. healthcheck endpoint.

This Nuxtjs doc suggests that this an expected pattern:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/nuxt-render